# How to #rewind the internal position under #each?

Tags: ruby, iterator, enumeration, enumerable, redo

I'm trying to write a code where the enumeration sequence is rewinded to the beginning.

I think `rewind` is appropriate for this application, but I'm not sure how to implement it under an `each` iterator passing to a block? In the Ruby-Docs example, `next` is used to move the internal position by one at a time. With a block, it would move autonomously.

There's not many good examples online for this specifically. My workaround at the moment is to nest an iterator under a loop and using `break` under the iterator. When the iterator breaks, the loop resets the enumeration sequence.

Is there a better way—as I'm sure there is—of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`Enumerator#rewind`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind) method from Ruby core class libarary.

> Rewinds the enumeration sequence to the beginning.If the enclosed object responds to a “rewind” method, it is called.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
enum= a.each
enum  # => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:each>
enum.next # => 1
enum.next  # => 2
enum.rewind # => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:each>
enum.next # => 1
```

Comment: I should specify. How would `each` be used passing to a block? In this example, `next` is used to move the internal position by one at a time. With a block, it would move autonomously.

Comment: @LambinJust read this http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each. All will be clear. `#each` gives `Enumerator` without block.

Comment: I was stubbornly confused at first, but the next day, I was like, "Arup was right! I get it now!" Thanks!